# Can't use the < (less than) symbol in JavaScript inside a JSP

Tags: javascript, jspx

I am trying to use the < symbol in a JavaScript function. This is causing a problem because it's the open-tag symbol too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ValidatePercentage() {

        int NetValue = document.getElementById("_id4:netValue").value;
        int GrassValue = document.getElementById("_id4:grassValue").value;

           int percentValue =  (NetValue/GrassValue);
               if percentValue<80 {
                    alert(percent value too small)
       }
}
</script>
```

I'm using JDeveloper version 10G. A red line appears under the < symbol just before the 80. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses with your if statement:

```
if (percentValue<80) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses and also your alert needed changing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function ValidatePercentage() {

        int NetValue = document.getElementById("_id4:netValue").value;
        int GrassValue = document.getElementById("_id4:grassValue").value;

           int percentValue =  (NetValue/GrassValue);
               if (percentValue<80) {
                    alert('percent value too small');
       }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still effects the < open tag further down the jsp

Comment: In that case we'll need to see the JSP further down the page

Answer (score 1):

Use a CDATA section.

Characters like "<" and "&" are illegal in XML elements.

"<" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.
"&" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.

Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of "<" or "&" characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.

Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

A CDATA section starts with **"<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>":**

Example

```
<script>
 <![CDATA[
  function matchwo(a,b){
   if (a < b && a < 0) then {
     return 1;
   } else {
     return 0;
   }
  }
  ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in 2018! Looks like turning around the comparison works as well. Instead of using '<' use '>'. In my case, I was trying to do

```
if ( i < 1 )
```

Instead I did

```
if ( i > 0 )
```

and obviously changed my code within the if block. So '>' is ok.